Is it "behavioral change" or "behavior change"?
I just noticed this one in a manuscript that I'm copyediting. The author is talking about "models for behavioral health", including the "Transtheoretical Model". At one point, she calls it the "Transtheoretical Model of Behavioral Change", and later, she calls it the "Transtheoretical Model of Behavior Change". Which is correct?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
